# Any issues with multiple services on the same server as the firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall

I am wondering if anyone has any input in regards to having one server as your firewall, backup server, email server, etc. I am trying to keep costs down and would like to know if there are any possible security concerns by placing everything on the same server. Thanks!

Comment: Not too sure this question belongs here as it is more a matter of practice than specific, actionable advice.

Comment: I am thinking this would get a far more nuanced and useful answer over on security.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: @Zoredache Possibly (and if they ask for it I'd certainly be willing to send it there), but it's at least tangentially on topic here - it's pretty well established that Best Practices are for firewalls to be dedicated devices...

Comment: @voretaq7, I was just thinking this could be written to ask 'why' this is the best practice, and what is the additional threats caused by multiple services.  This could be rewritten in a way to encourage answers with far more information.

Comment: @Zoredache Absolutely - the "Why" behind this best practice is definitely a topic for [security.SE] (if it hasn't already been covered there).

Answer (score 6):

Putting anything on your firewall is a bad idea. The point of a firewall is to secure things *behind* it, and it's not doing its job if everything's on one box!

If you must, go with a standard SOHO router you can buy in most stores and use the box for your services. In general a firewall should be on dedicated hardware.

Comment: This. If you are running ANYTHING on your firewall (except possibly an SSH server to get in and configure the thing) you are ***Doing It Wrong*** and inviting breaches.

Comment: Great answer, Nathan and solid supporting advice Voretaq. @ Jeff - think of it in an abstracted sense: you wouldn't want to filter dirt / debris inside a motorcycle's carburetor - the function is delegated to the air filter. the Firewall is your airfilter in this situation. Good luck!

Comment: The question is fine -- just more about best practices and theory than specific configuration issues and probably better for the IT Security exchange.